# VBA - If cell contains string then replace cell with first letter

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have a column (A) which contains some data about questions answered. Some lines are blank and others contain "2 (out of 2)" i.e. they answered 2 out of 2 questions but this can vary (3 out of 3, 6 out of 6, 10 out of 10, ...).

All i'm interested in seeing in this column is the first number, otherwise it can remain blank.

I'm trying to create a macro that goes through the range and if a cell contains *"(out of"* it is replaced this with a *left function, 1* but I'm having some difficulty.

I found this script on another post which worked on a test page I made, but it doesn't seem to work on my actual data?

```
Dim owb As Excel.Workbook
Set owb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim mystr As String
RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(owb.Sheets("RFP").Range("A:A"))
For i = 2 To RowCount
    mystr = Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    If InStr(mystr, "(out of") > 0 Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Left(mystr, InStr(mystr, "(out of"))
    End If
Next
```

I don't really understand what the 'For i = 2 To RowCount' means. Is the above on the right lines and how do i replace what is in the relevant cells in Column A with a formula?

Thanks
Alan

------------[This is the current format of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnQet.png)

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

The following code should clear up the issues (assuming the issue is that you're left with a trailing opening parenthesis).

```
Sub Test()
    Dim owb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sWorking As Worksheet
    Dim rAnchor As Range
    Dim nLastRow As Long
    Dim nLastCol As Long
    Dim rAnalyze As Range

    Set owb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sWorking = owb.Sheets("RFP")

    'Below anchors where the range to work on starts. If this can vary, you have to change
    'to best reflect the start point.

    Set rAnchor = sWorking.Range("I12")

    'Determine the last row in the anchor's column
    nLastRow = sWorking.Cells(Rows.Count, rAnchor.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    'Determine the last column the in the anchor's row
    nLastCol = sWorking.Cells(rAnchor.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set rAnalyze = sWorking.Range(rAnchor, sWorking.Cells(nLastRow, nLastCol))

    For Each cel In rAnalyze
        mystr = Trim(cel.Value)
        If InStr(mystr, "(out of") > 0 Then
            cel.Value = Left(mystr, InStr(mystr, "(out of") - 2)
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

As far as the `For`, it just loops through all of the cells in your column. The `COUNTA` method that you originally used won't work correctly if you have blank cells, so I changed it.

Let us know more specifically what you need with a resulting formula in the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added an image above of how the excel document looks. As you can see i'm trying to update any cell in Column I onwards that contains '(out of' to be just the first number.  In this case they all need to be 2 but there is no limit on how many columns or row there can be

Comment: @Alan The code doesn't change much. All you need to do differently is change the range upon which you are working, and that will depend on your business rules. I'll make an edit to my above post to do just that, but it's important that you understand how the code determines the range to work upon in case your business rules actually differ.